# Google places details Json response parsing stops when a value is blank

Tags: android, json, google-places-api

I am trying to parse a JSON response received from google places details, and trying to populate a custom object.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
JSONObject placeDetailsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONObject("result");

googlePlaceDetails placeDetails = new googlePlaceDetails();

placeDetails.placeName = placeDetailsJsonArray.getString("name");
placeDetails.placeAddress = placeDetailsJsonArray.getString("formatted_address");
placeDetails.vicinity = placeDetailsJsonArray.getString("vicinity");
placeDetails.phoneNo =placeDetailsJsonArray.getString("international_phone_number");
placeDetails.website =placeDetailsJsonArray.getString("website");
placeDetails.socialPage = placeDetailsJsonArray.getString("url");
placeDetails.rating = placeDetailsJsonArray.getString("rating");

JSONObject geometry = placeDetailsJsonArray.getJSONObject("geometry");
JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");

placeDetails.lat = location.getString("lat");
placeDetails.lng = location.getString("lng");
```

the class GooglePlaceDetails is very simple with just few String values

```
public class googlePlaceDetails {
String placeName;
String placeAddress;
String vicinity;
String phoneNo;
String website;
String socialPage;
String rating;
String lat;
String lng;
}
```

The code works fine when all the values are present in the JSON response, but when one value is not present (say International Phone number), then the code throws exception, and the remaining values are not processed at all.

Here is a [sample JSON response](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJc1pfHNlwAjoRmFBHptMBWwM&key=AIzaSyBWKQHS39-SYUNxEEAry1FxrMET2NwhqxE) which does not have the international phone number.

**LOGCAT:**

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for international_phone_number
        at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:515)
        at manasthemarvel.travelflow.PlaceAPI.getPlaceDetails(PlaceAPI.java:83)
        at manasthemarvel.travelflow.placeInfoMap.doInBackground(place_info.java:107)
        at manasthemarvel.travelflow.placeInfoMap.doInBackground(place_info.java:103)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

How do I skip a value when it is not present and continue parsing the remaining values?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by creating a method for checking if the value exists.

```
private String checkEmptyJsonResponse(JSONObject jsonArray, String jsonKey)
{
    try {
        if (jsonArray.has(jsonKey))
            return jsonArray.getString(jsonKey);
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }

    return "Not Available";
}
```